# Execute bash script on files in different folders

Tags: linux, bash

I have several files with the same name in different folders. I want to execute my bash script to all of them in parallel. Is it possible to put them in a separate .txt file or in the same bash script and execute?i.e,

all.tab file

```
path/to/set1/my.bam
path/to/set2/my.bam
path/to/set3/my.bam
```

and a bash,

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#$ -q cluster_name
#$ -cwd
#$ -N job_name
#$ -e /path/to/log
#$ -o /path/to/log
#$ -l job_mem=16G
#$ -pe serial 4

PICARD="path/to/picard"
BAM="/path/to/all.tab"

echo "validating bam file"

$PICARD/picard.jar ValidateSamFile I=$BAM MODE=SUMMARY
```

So that it is going to launch several jobs to gueue in parallel and write log outputs or other output files in the respective folders.
If there is any other way, I appreciate any help.
EDIT: I invoke it as: qsub ./test.sh

Comment: How to invoke the shell script and which are the files to invoke on?

Comment: You mean it as `qsub ./test.sh path/to/set1/my.bam`, `qsub ./test.sh path/to/set2/my.bam`, etc?

Comment: No, because I want the script to be executed on variable BAM that take all files in the tab file. I am sorry if it is confusing..

Comment: Am afraid its quite vague! atleast to me

Comment: I don't know how to explain better than this. I have several my.bam files in different folders and I want to execute 1 single bash script on all of them, launching only once qsub ./test.sh

Comment: Can you give feedback if my answer does help in any way?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **[find](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html)** command in order to first "find" all files with that given name within your directory structure.

Then you can use **[xargs](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-xargs-construct-argument-lists-utility/)** using its "-P" option in order to run commands on that output of find in **parallel**.

See [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/193319/a-better-unix-find-with-parallel-processing) for further details.

Comment: Hi, so I did use parallel, but this is not exactly what I was looking for, I need something like array in which one command line works for several hundreds of files.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something like this (but may be a more elegant ways exist).

```
PICARD="path/to/picard"
BAMFILES="path/to/set1/test.bam
path/to/set2/test.bam
path/to/set3/test.bam"

for f in $BAMFILES
do 
    $PICARD/picard.jar ValidateSamFile I=$f MODE=SUMMARY
done
```

Comment: Probably you should **clarify** your own idea. You talk about doing things in parallel; but your own solution here ... doesn't. You see, your little script is nothing but a wrapper to some other (java based) tool. What difference does it make if your script is invoked 50 times; or if the script is invoked 1 time, but then loops over 50 entries given to it? Seriously: if you want to do things **in parallel**, then just look into my solution. As in general: simply try to built on top of existing tools instead of re-inventing your own tooling.

Comment: It was an example. I posted my question here to get some suggestion. I am looking into your solution, but for a person who started with bash yday, this is not so straightforward. thanks anyway

Comment: OK, got it. And hint for the bash newbie: try to do as **less** things with bash scripts. Yes, you can script down many things with bash, but there is a **ton** of things that you can get wrong when you just started using it. Thus: if you find solutions that work without you writing bash code, prefer those.